# Which rxjava3 retrofit-adapter should we use for Rxjava3

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-java2

I am using RxJava3 and retrofit but I am unable to get a  rxjava3 retrofit-adapter for RxJava3.

Comment: It seems there is no support yet though you can find a workaround here
https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3158

Comment: I've released a fresh adapter version to match RxJava 3.0.0: https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaRetrofitAdapter#rxjavaretrofitadapter (I thought Retrofit official will do their version in the meantime, but apparently not.)

Comment: implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava3:2.9.0' we can use like  .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create())

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There is now an official Retrofit implementation with version 2.9.0:

Just use the adapter where you create your Retrofit client:

```
val rxAdapter = RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create()
retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
            .client(httpClient)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(rxAdapter).build()
```

And include the RxAdapter dependency in your `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava3:2.9.0'
```

https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-290-2020-05-20

Also from the documentation:

> Unlike the RxJava 1 and RxJava 2 adapters, the RxJava 3 adapter's create() method will produce asynchronous HTTP requests by default. For synchronous requests use createSynchronous() and for synchronous on a scheduler use createWithScheduler(..)

Comment: Being the only version makes me feel uncomfortable...

Answer (score 6):

Use the *[RxJavaRetrofitAdapter](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaRetrofitAdapter#rxjavaretrofitadapter)* library by **@akarnokd**.

`implementation "com.github.akarnokd:rxjava3-retrofit-adapter:3.0.0"`

Answer (score 0):

Use the

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava3:2.9.0'
```